Artifact Null on extract from the dependency
I am having a working module, I am trying to inject the module into new application not using the compose version 1.8.2 in my application, even though its checking for 1.8.2 in my cached folder and facing the build exception as below
Null extracted folder for artifact: ResolvedArtifact(componentIdentifier=androidx.activity:activity:1.8.2, variantName=null, artifactFile=/Users/arunkumar/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/androidx.activity/activity/1.8.2/bce54c84024b17c34f9d4cdeaf1ce39d3e750c9e/activity-1.8.2.aar, extractedFolder=null, dependencyType=ANDROID, isWrappedModule=false, buildMapping={__current_build__=/Users/AndroidProjects/android_native_container}, mavenCoordinatesCache=com.android.build.gradle.internal.ide.dependencies.MavenCoordinatesCacheBuildService$Inject@6256b201)

 // For Compose UI
compose_ui_version = '1.1.1'
implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:1.4.0-alpha03"
implementation "androidx.compose.compiler:compiler:1.4.3"
implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:1.4.0-alpha03"
implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.6.1'
debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:1.4.0-alpha03"
debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest:$compose_ui_version"
implementation "androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.1.1"
androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_ui_version"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.4.0-rc01"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:1.0.0-alpha07"

I am using the build gradle support as
android {
compileSdkVersion = 34
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.aaa.containerApp"
    minSdk 31
    targetSdkVersion 34
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0.0.0"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    compileOptions.incremental = false
    dataBinding.enabled = true
    multiDexEnabled true
    resConfigs "en"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}}

Any idea on the issue will be appreciated
